# Integral Calc Proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Let $f (p/q) = 1/q$ if the fraction $p/q$ is in lowest terms and $f (x) = 0$ for irrational $x$.
Prove that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if and only if $x$ is irrational or $x = 0$.

Comment: in My chinese analysis book it was called "Riemann function" but i can't wiki it without finding "Riemann zeta function"...

Comment: and i think the definition has a little wrong place,the function should be defined in $(0,1)$ and $f(0)=f(1)=0$ Found it in the wikipedia...http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function...I don't know why in all chinese analysis book it's called riemann function...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** : just prove the limit of every point is all zero.